# Animated List Rearrangement (JQuery UI Sortable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a sortable listed thats animated.

- Apples
- Bananas
- Cavemen

Let's say I've selected Apples and I want to switch it with Cavemen, I want to click on Apples, drag it to cavemen and have bannas and cave men animate up to the proper positions.

I am aware that JQuery UI Sortable allows for some level of this functionality, but I'm not sure if there is a way to specify something during a pause before the DOM changes or through some cloning.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
    change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Would it be possible to manipulate `sortable` to provide this level of functionality, or would I be better off writing a plugin from scratch?

Comment: What you've described: "Let's say I've selected Apples and I want to switch it with Cavemen, I want to click on Apples, drag it to cavemen and have bannas and cave men animate up to the proper positions." seems to be exactly how sortable works. Is there some more functionality that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

See this page for more detail: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-start